# Node JS - Problems with npm when installing plugin

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install cordova-plugin-camera

When I try 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera" I get this error:

```
(node:10036) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera@2.3" via plugin registry

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.17.177.14:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

Does someone know what would be the reason why it is happening? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating `npm`:

```
sudo npm update -g npm
```

You can check your npm version by

```
npm --version
```

**EDIT**:

Try installing *corodova-plugin-camera* from url directly:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

For more details visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera)

Comment: I am sorry, I just started using StackOverFlow. Do you know if there is any difference between 'cordova-plugin-camera' and 'cordova-plugin-camera-preview'?

Comment: I didnt see that and yes there is a huge difference you can read about both here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera and https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera-preview , again try edit

Comment: I finally fixed that by removing and adding cordova again! I really appreciate your help... I was having a really hard time with that